# How Can I change Image mb size with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I need to compress the size of my image after upload and before save it to my backend server. I have tried shortpixel for changing size but it requires save the file to my server. I want to do that before saving. How can I fix it in nodejs?

Comment: Can you provide more context as to how the file is being received by your backend server, what multi-part form packages you might be using as well as some code for us to help you debug. Please review the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the [Sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) package. Most popular javascript library for image resize.